# OwnClound: Rename login not possible?

Tags: owncloud

I would like to rename a login in owncloud.

According to this issue it is to possible at the moment:

https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/1333

It is 100% ok if it is not possible via web GUI.

But I guess it is possible with shell and sql.

Can someone explain how to do it?

## My use case:

I have uploaded a huge directory to the wrong account. Uploading again would take several days.

## work around

A different solution would be do move the data from one account to an other.

Answer (score 2):

No, renaming the user is not possible as the *developer* of the system told multiple times on the linked page. They consider the username an immutable ID.

Moving the data from one user to another would be a different question.

Comment: Why is it "not possible"? ... because they consider it immutable. AFAIK I can modify every byte on my hard disk. Maybe the name is stored on several places. Changing a primary key in a database is possible, too. You just need to be sure to update all foreign keys which reference the primary key.

Comment: Yeah, then have fun doing it, against the recommendation of the developers. Don't expect to get help with it anywhere....

Comment: Please define "anywhere".

Comment: Pick up a dictionary ...